# Mustache - conditionally render a list from array data

Tags: javascript, mustache, handlebars.js

I've got an existing app which uses Mustache.js for templating and I'm needing to conditionally render a list from array data (json) coming from the server.  Is this possible with Mustache?

Some example data:

```
"Preferences": ["pref-red", "pref-blue"]
```

Easy enough to output that via:

```
<ul class="plain">
    {{#Preferences}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/Preferences}}
</ul>
```

But what I really want to do is conditionally render the appropriate parts of a static list based on whatever preferences data comes back. Some really dumb psuedo code:

```
<ul class="plain">
    {{#Preferences}}
        {{if pref-red}}<li class="icon red bell">Red</li>{{/if}}
        {{if pref-green}}<li class="icon green car">Green</li>{{/if}}
        {{if pref-blue}}<li class="icon blue cat">Blue</li>{{/if}}
        {{if pref-yellow}}<li class="icon yellow flower">Yellow</li>{{/if}}
        {{if pref-purple}}<li class="icon purple house">Purple</li>{{/if}}
    {{/Preferences}}
</ul>
```

Which would in this case output in the browser as:

```
<ul class="plain">
    <li class="icon red bell">Red</li>
    <li class="icon blue cat">Blue</li>
</ul>
```

I know Mustache doesn't have if conditions, but can this be achieved in Mustache?  I'd like to keep it to Mustache if possible (reduce, reuse, recycle).

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not be achieved by Mustache with your raw data as it is.

Your two options:

- Transform your input data so that it can be rendered by Mustache.
- Change rendering engine. You have yourself added the handlebars.js tag to your question: you already have an answer.